# I need to vlookup in a close book without opening it. But i only get #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

```
Function csimplex(CODIGO As String)

    Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mvela\Documents\Prueba.xlsm").Worksheets("Simplex").Range("A:Z")

    csimplex = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CODIGO, rg, 3, False)

End Function
```

Comment: But in your code you are opening "Prueba.xlsm" `Workbook`, so I'm confused here

Comment: Im new in this, so any help would be really apreciated. I vlookup in a closed book in a diferent directory

Comment: @MartinVelascoOrmeño You just need to explicitly refer to the workbook/worksheet in the vlookup.

Comment: The easy way is to let excel build the lookup for you. Open both workbooks your working with and write the vlookup and then close the workbook you want to look into.  Excel will auto write the formula to look inside that closed book. Then build your custom function based off of the formula left in the open book. I think you can even record the process and it will write the process out in VBA .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a closed workbook in VBA, not with VLOOKUP, not with EVALUATE. The solution is to quickly snap the workbook open, return the value then close the workbook.

```
Function csimplex(CODIGO As String) As Variant

    Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mvela\Documents\Prueba.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets("Simplex").Range("A:Z")

    csimplex = Application.VLookup(CODIGO, rng, 3, False)

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False   `<~~ CLOSE THE WORKBOOK!

End Function
```

An .XLSB is smaller than an otherwise identical .XLSM and will load, retrieve and close faster. If you were to do this a large number of times, then you could build a static array of the values and use that.

Comment: I am not sure that it is not possible in VBA to look in a closed workbook but their are plenty of formulas out there that will. On the other hand Plus 1 on you bottom statement.  .xlsb is the way to go. Have a great day!

Comment: You're correct. It works as a function called from a sub procedure but not as a worksheet function.

Comment: What is CODIGO? Is it really a string, integer,,,,? remove "as Variant"  and just use "Function csimplex(CODIGO As Variant)".  Not the best practice but it can narrow down your error.  The error is most likely cause your not matching the right variable of the Cell your looking at.

Comment: Jeeped - assuming he loops this function called by a sub he will run into a nightmare of problems and need error catchers for unmatched items because using VBA vlookups suck. On top of the slowest macro known to man. Opening then and closing a workbook over and over assuming it does not lock up excel for using up all the memory. Please don't get me wrong your method works but you know there are better ways to do this but it is time consuming to write it all out. If he wants to  use this it would be best to make is a sub all together then loop then close the workbook.

Comment: @Ricky - Well, I did mention something about a static array (e.g. `static vals as variant`) but that was the 'next step'.

Comment: @Jeeped - i hear ya bud! No disrespect at all! It made me cringe a little seeing you say call it by a sub knowing it would be opening and closing a workbook over and over. You are 100% correct on static array but not knowing if he only needs this for one or two items your first method would be good solution.

Comment: Just use this formula e.g.        
    =VLOOKUP(A6,'C:\Users\mvela\Documents\[Prueba.xlsm]Simplex'!$A:$Z,3,FALSE) there is a \ after Documents but it does not show up in comments

Comment: @Ricky I already try to use that formula, but still the same #VALUE. Does anyone knows hoy to import a range from a close book? Or any other method. The files will be in a local server but you can not save in that server.

Comment: When I compile it aperars Expected: Espression at ' before C:\

Answer (score 0):

I even tested it. Open the workbook you want closed copy a value in column A and paste it in A1 of the book you want open and place the code below in B1. Close the book and see if it works. That error means the column the vlookup is referencing is finding no matching values. Which usually means it is a format issue.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Users\mvela\Documents\[Prueba.xlsm]Simple‌​x'!$A:$Z,3,FALSE)
```

See if that is the issue first bud.

We can try to get fancy with it.

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\mvela\Documents\
[Prueba.xlsm]Simplex'!$D:$D,MATCH(A1,'C:\Users\mvela\Documents\
[Prueba.xlsm]Simplex'!$A:$A,0))
```

Try this, You may like it more:

```
Option Explicit


Function csimplex(CODIGO As String) As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set wb = Workbooks("Prueba.xlsm")

Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("Simplex").Range("A:A")
Set rng2 = wb.Worksheets("Simplex").Range("C:C")

On Error Resume Next

    csimplex = Application.Index(rng2, Application.Match(CODIGO, rng1, 0))

On Error GoTo 0


End Function
```

NVM that is if it is open. I have the code some where. I will keep digging.

Comment: I even tested it on a different server and it worked on read only.

Comment: When I compile it aperars Expected: Espression at ' before C:\